# How to average the summed up values in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Using MongoDB 2.4.8,

I have the following records

```
{
    "category" : "TOYS",
    "price" : 12,
    "status" : "online",
    "_id" : "35043"
}
{
    "category" : "TOYS",
    "price" : 13,
    "status" : "offline",
    "_id" : "35044"
}
{
    "category" : "TOYS",
    "price" : 22,
    "status" : "online",
    "_id" : "35045"
}
{
    "category" : "BOOKS",
    "price" : 13,
    "status" : "offline",
    "_id" : "35046"
}
{
    "category" : "BOOKS",
    "price" : 17,
    "status" : "online",
    "_id" : "35047"
}
```

I want to find the average price of each category whose status is online and total price is more than 50.

I am not sure how to construct this query.

So far, I can construct the query where I summed up and find out the total price for each category whose status is online.

```
db.products.aggregate([
    {"$match":
        {           
            {status:"online"}
        }
    },
    {"$group" :
        {
            "_id": "$category",
            "total_price": {$sum:"$price"},
        }
    }
])
```

I am not sure how to add more stages to this query to get the averages I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add more stages to your aggregation pipeline. For example:

```
db.items.aggregate([
    {$match:
        {           
            status:"online"
        }
    },
    {$group :
        {
            _id: "$category",
            total_price: {$sum:"$price"},
        }
    },
    {$match:
        {           
            total_price:{$gt:50}
        }
    },
    {$group :
        {
            _id: "1",
            avg_price: {$avg:"$total_price"},
        }
    },
]);
```

EDITTED based on clarifications

Comment: I had thought of something similar, but was afraid I would get average per product rather than average per category. Would this query avoid this issue?

Comment: All aggregations in the $group aggregation operation work over the set defined in the "_id" field. So, yes, it averages by category. I tested it in the mongo shell and it does what is expected.

Comment: Okay, what I meant is we totalled up all the prices and then divide by the number of categories.

Comment: Looks like Stennie and I are giving identical solutions at the same time, I'm going to just upvote his answer and sit this out.

Comment: Ok, I was bored enough to update my answer. Please check it and see if that's what you need.

Comment: Oh I didn't know you can stack the $group this way. Cool. Thank you, @Simplefish.

Comment: @Simplefish: didn't see your post until I refreshed the page .. indeed the same :)

Comment: @Stennie: I saw Simplefish answer first, so I awarded him the tick. Hope that is okay with you. :)

Comment: @KimStacks: No worries, I upvoted it too ;).  Would have passed if I saw there was already a good answer.

Comment: Oops. Sorry guys, I just realized I have an additional requirement to the original question. Should I continue here or create a new question?

Comment: @KimStacks: A separate question would be clearer, unless the requirement can be addressed quickly in a comment. Multiple edits are confusing as the answers may no longer match up with the question.

Comment: I create a separate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865572/how-to-ensure-grouping-via-two-separate-criteria

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the average product price per category in the `$group` step with the total, and then add an extra `$match` stage to limit the results to products with total of more than 50:

```
db.products.aggregate(

    // Find matching products (can take advantage of index)
    { $match: {
        status: "online"
    }},

    // Calculate total and average
    { $group: {
        "_id": "$category",
        "total_price": { $sum:"$price" },
        "avg_price": { $avg:"$price"} 
    }},

    // Limit results to price > 50
    { $match: {
        "total_price" : { $gt: 50 }
    }}
)
```

Note that with your example data, there would be no matching results for `$gt:50` (you could instead try with `$gt:30` to get the "TOYS" category as a match with total price of 34).

#### Averaging total prices for matching categories

If you want to get the average price for the total prices of the categories matching the limit, you can add an extra `$group` step at the end:

```
// Calculate the average total price
{ $group: {
    "_id": null,
    "total_average_price": { $avg:"$total_price"} 
}}
```

Note that this extra grouping is going to reduce everything down to one number (the `total_average_price`) which may or may not be what you expect.  You might want to save the intermediate results before running the aggregation with the last group, or just calculate the average in your application code if there aren't a lot of numbers to sum up.

Comment: I had thought of something similar, but was afraid I would get average per product rather than average per category. Would this query avoid this issue?

Comment: The `$avg` is calculated on the grouping criteria which is currently by category (i.e. the average product price per category). Are you instead after the average of the total prices for the categories? If so, you can calculate it in an extract `$project` step after the `$group`.

Comment: Sorry for my misstatement. yes I am after the average of the total prices for the categories. Meaning to say, we take all the total prices of all the categories divided by the number of categories.