# How to ensure grouping via two separate criteria

Tags: mongodb

Expanded from [How to average the summed up values in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20864848/80353)

Using MongoDB 2.4.8,

I have the following records

```
{
    "category" : "TOYS",
    "price" : 12,
    "status" : "online",
    "_id" : "35043"
}
{
    "category" : "TOYS",
    "price" : 13,
    "status" : "offline",
    "_id" : "35044"
}
{
    "category" : "TOYS",
    "price" : 22,
    "status" : "online",
    "_id" : "35045"
}
{
    "category" : "BOOKS",
    "price" : 13,
    "status" : "offline",
    "_id" : "35046"
}
{
    "category" : "BOOKS",
    "price" : 17,
    "status" : "online",
    "_id" : "35047"
}
{
    "category" : "TOYS",
    "price" : 19,
    "status" : "unavailable",
    "_id" : "35048"
}
{
    "category" : "BOOKS",
    "price" : 10,
    "status" : "unavailable",
    "_id" : "35049"
}
{
    "category" : "BOOKS",
    "price" : 17,
    "status" : "unavailable",
    "_id" : "35050"
}
```

I want to find the average price of all categories whose status is online OR offline and total price within a category is more than 50.

Toys offline and Toys online are considered two separate categories.

I adapted the answer given.

```
db.items.aggregate([
    {$match:
        {    
            $or: [       
              {status:"online"},
              {status:"offline"}
            ]
        }
    },
    {$group :
        {
            _id: "$category",
            total_price: {$sum:"$price"},
        }
    },
    {$match:
        {           
            total_price:{$gt:50}
        }
    },
    {$group :
        {
            _id: "1",
            avg_price: {$avg:"$total_price"},
        }
    },
]);
```

But I believe this query I adapted grouped categories of the same name together which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If online and offline are the only values for `status`, you can remove the initial `$match` step. If it is needed, it would be more appropriate to use the  [`$in` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) as these values could be found in the same index (if one existed).

I think the only step you are missing is that you can `$group` by multiple fields (i.e. category and status):

```
db.items.aggregate(

    // If 'online' and 'offline' are the only possible status values, this may be unnecessary
    { $match: {
        'status' : { $in: [ 'online', 'offline' ] }
    }},

    // Group by category & status
    { $group: {
        _id: { category: "$category", status: "$status" },
       total_price: { $sum: "$price" },
    }},

    // Only find groups where total_price is > 50
    { $match: {
        total_price: { $gt:50 }
    }},

    // Find the average price for the group
    { $group : {
        _id: null,
        avg_price: {$avg:"$total_price"},
    }}

)
```

Comment: This is a bit of a side track.

I am very comfortable with sql queries. I can do this same thing with mysql. However, I am not fluent at all with mongo. I narrowed my weakness with mongo to the fact that I do not know WHEN to use $ and WHEN not to. E.g.  `{ category: "$category", status: "$status" },` `total_price: { $sum: "$price" },` `avg_price: {$avg:"$total_price"},` notice how the last 2 code snippets the total_price refers to the same value but one of them has $ the other does not. Btw, your query works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: In the Aggregation Framework you use "$fieldname" when you want to evaluate that field value in an expression (i.e. it appears on the *right-hand side* of a label in a `$project` or `$group` stage). If you want the literal field name (i.e. as used on the *left-hand side* of a projection) you do not prefix with `$`.  So "total_price" is a field name; "$total_price" is the value of the `total_price` field.

Comment: In other words, $ is always used for value and would be on right hand side of the colon sign. Of course key words like $proejct and $group and $in not withstanding. Correct?

Comment: Correct. To add to the use of `$` .. if it appears on the left-hand side of an expression (i.e. as `$group` or `$avg`), that usage is indicating an aggregation command rather than a field value.

Comment: Thank you, @Stennie. I have learned from this. By the way, I am stuck in another aggregare related query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915148/how-to-do-group-in-aggregate-but-also-show-other-fields-using-mongo Hope you are able to advise?